# Why is \chapter blocking page foot?

Tags: header-footer

Why is the footnote not displayed when I add a chapter to my document?

This code is working:

```
\documentclass[10pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf} %package used for drawing
\usepackage{color}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

And this one is not working:

```
\documentclass[10pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf} %package used for drawing
\usepackage{color}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\chapter{Not working}%just added this line
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean footer instead of footnote? More specifically are you referring to the "footer rule" in the first example? First pages of chapter tend to have a different page style than other chapters (usually they don't need a running head with the chapter name, sometimes they even omit the page number): That is what is happening here.

Comment: the `fancyhdr` package that you are using has special commands to customise the page foot used on chapter openings and similar (look for `fancyplain` in the manual)

Comment: Something like `\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \rfoot{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}` could work, but you should better wait for an expert to come up with something more elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chapter pages uses page style `plain` by default. Package `fancyhdr` does not redefine `plain` automatically. You could use either `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` to redefine the plain style:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{a fancy page}
\newcommand*\fancyrulewidth{.4pt}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{\fancyrulewidth}
\renewcommand*\footrulewidth{\fancyrulewidth}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[L]{a plain page}% different settings for plain pages
  \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{\fancyrulewidth}
  \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{\fancyrulewidth}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Not working}
\section{Section}
\clearpage
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you can use page style `fancyplain`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}% redefines the plain style too
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\fancyplain{a plain page}{a fancy page}}% <- example for different settings for plain and fancy pages

\newcommand*\fancyrulewidth{.4pt}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{\fancyrulewidth}
\renewcommand*\footrulewidth{\fancyrulewidth}
\renewcommand*\plainheadrulewidth{\fancyrulewidth}
\renewcommand*\plainfootrulewidth{\fancyrulewidth}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Not working}
\section{Section}
\clearpage
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.